# Mixture of UK and US Dates - Convert All to UK

Tags: mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I have just realised that after importing 8 million records into the database (long time!) that sadly some dates are mixed (UK and US format, not good!)

i.e.

26/03/2015
22/12/2014
10/08/2012
11/17/2011
11/30/2010

Not only this, the column of the database is varchar, which isnt good for performance either.

I have made a test database and I have tried this with fail:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)
```

I'm trying to get the UK dates i.e. 25/11/1992 and not 11/25/1992

Any help would be great otherwise thats a night wasted uploading data!

Comment: This is simply a corrupt data, if you have dates in mixed format unless there is a column which tells you that what format it is, you cannot be 100% sure which ones are US or UK dates, as `01/03/2013` is first of march in UK and 3rd of January in US unless you know what type of date it is there is no way of telling what it should really be, US or UK date, I would go back to the location from where the data was extracted and get valid data extracts

Comment: Is there another column in the table that signifies the country the entry is for?

Comment: You can find the reliably wrong ones where the day value is larger than 12.  That's easy.  Where the day (and month) value are in the range 1..12, you're snookered; it could be a US or a UK format date.  There's no knowing without some extra information which is correct.  If you're lucky, there's another date field in the same record that indicates whether the record as a whole was in US or UK format.  There are bound to be records where that doesn't happen.  So sad; the data is basically worthless unless you know whether it was 12th January or 1st December — that's a big difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way of the select on your example is like this:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)
```

But i was thinking of two solution 
make a function the take a varchar of US date and return varchar of UK date
but the big problem you don´t know if in table all the date is US type, if you can figure witch surly what type of the date you just resolved the problem, and you can put this rule on the function passing some params that help to figure that.

also you don´t need to import all the data again, after you make the above things just make an update statement of the current table using the function.

good luck.